# Deleting a file from S3 using Django + Fineuploader + boto

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, fine-uploader

I am having trouble deleting a file from S3 using Fineuploader and Django/boto. I am able to successfully upload files to S3 with Fineuploader, and retrieve and display the image url, but deleting hasn't been successful.

From looking at the boto debug logs, it looks like boto is not sending the token as part of the request to S3 and I think that may be my problem.

First I have the boto debug output because I suspect someone more familiar with it can help after just looking at it, but I have my full setup afterwards  (which follows the example at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/python/django-fine-uploader-s3/ as closely as possible)

**terminal output on delete**

```
bucket_name:  XXXXXXXX
key_name: b45069b8-dc44-45fe-8b67-b25fc088bdea.jpg
aws_bucket:  <Bucket: XXXXXXXXX>
aws_key:  <Key: XXXXXXXX,b45069b8-dc44-45fe-8b67-b25fc088bdea.jpg>
2014-04-17 15:01:56,576 boto [DEBUG]:path=/b45069b8-dc44-45fe-8b67-b25fc088bdea.jpg
2014-04-17 15:01:56,577 boto [DEBUG]:auth_path=/thisorthis/b45069b8-dc44-45fe-8b67-b25fc088bdea.jpg
2014-04-17 15:01:56,577 boto [DEBUG]:Method: DELETE
2014-04-17 15:01:56,577 boto [DEBUG]:Path: /b45069b8-dc44-45fe-8b67-b25fc088bdea.jpg
2014-04-17 15:01:56,577 boto [DEBUG]:Data:
2014-04-17 15:01:56,577 boto [DEBUG]:Headers: {}
2014-04-17 15:01:56,577 boto [DEBUG]:Host: XXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com
2014-04-17 15:01:56,578 boto [DEBUG]:Port: 443
2014-04-17 15:01:56,578 boto [DEBUG]:Params: {}
2014-04-17 15:01:56,578 boto [DEBUG]:establishing HTTPS connection: host=thisorthis.s3.amazonaws.com, kwargs={'port': 443, 'timeout': 70}
2014-04-17 15:01:56,578 boto [DEBUG]:Token: None
2014-04-17 15:01:56,578 boto [DEBUG]:StringToSign:
DELETE


Thu, 17 Apr 2014 15:01:56 GMT
/XXXXXXXX/b45069b8-dc44-45fe-8b67-b25fc088bdea.jpg
2014-04-17 15:01:56,579 boto [DEBUG]:Signature:
AWS AKIAJYS27FQSNHPH3CXQ:dVKlBpulsY9LrOtHOa+xQmurIEM=
[17/Apr/2014 15:01:57] "DELETE /s3/delete/b45069b8-dc44-45fe-8b67-b25fc088bdea?key=b45069b8-dc44-45fe-8b67-b25fc088bdea.jpg&bucket=XXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 500 15975
```

**settings.py:**

```
AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY") 
AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY")
AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY")

AWS_EXPECTED_BUCKET = 'mybucketname'
AWS_MAX_SIZE = 15000000
```

Obviously I have my actual bucket name there, as I said uploading is working so I don't think the issue is in the settings.

**Fineuploader Instance**

```
  $("#fine-uploader).fineUploaderS3({
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: 'XXXXX',
            accessKey: 'XXXXXXXX'
        },

        template: "simple-previews-template",

        signature: {
            endpoint: '/s3/signature/'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: '/s3/success/'
        },

        iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
        },

        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: '/s3/delete/'
        },

        classes: {
           dropActive: "cssClassToAddToDropZoneOnEnter"
        },

    })
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^s3/signature/', views.handle_s3, name="s3_signee"),
url(r'^s3/delete/', views.handle_s3, name='s3_delete'),
url(r'^s3/success/', views.success_redirect_endpoint, name="s3_succes_endpoint")
```

**views.py**

```
try:
    import boto
    from boto.s3.connection import Key, S3Connection
    boto.set_stream_logger('boto')
    S3 = S3Connection(development.AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY, development.AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY)
except ImportError, e:
    print("Could not import boto, the Amazon SDK for Python.")
    print("Deleting files will not work.")
    print("Install boto with")
    print("$ pip install boto")



@csrf_exempt
def success_redirect_endpoint(request):
    """ This is where the upload will snd a POST request after the 
    file has been stored in S3.
    """

    key = request.POST.get('key')
    response = {}
    response['url'] = key
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")


@csrf_exempt
def handle_s3(request):
    """ View which handles all POST and DELETE requests sent by Fine Uploader
    S3. You will need to adjust these paths/conditions based on your setup.
    """

    if request.method == "POST":
        return handle_POST(request)
    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        return handle_DELETE(request)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=405)

def handle_POST(request):
    """ Handle S3 uploader POST requests here. For files <=5MiB this is a simple
    request to sign the policy document. For files >5MiB this is a request
    to sign the headers to start a multipart encoded request.
    """

    if request.POST.get('success', None):
        return make_response(200)
    else:
        request_payload = json.loads(request.body)
        headers = request_payload.get('headers', None)

        if headers:
            print "headers"
            # The presence of the 'headers' property in the request payload 
            # means this is a request to sign a REST/multipart request 
            # and NOT a policy document
            response_data = sign_headers(headers)
        else:
            print "no headers"
            if not is_valid_policy(request_payload):
                print "is not valid"
                return make_response(400, {'invalid': True})

            response_data = sign_policy_document(request_payload)
        response_payload = json.dumps(response_data)
        return make_response(200, response_payload)

def handle_DELETE(request):
    """ Handle file deletion requests. For this, we use the Amazon Python SDK,
    boto.
    """
    print "handle delete"
    if boto:
        bucket_name = request.REQUEST.get('bucket')
        print "bucket_name: ", bucket_name
        key_name = request.REQUEST.get('key')
        print "key_name:", key_name
        aws_bucket = S3.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=False)
        print "aws_bucket: ", aws_bucket
        aws_key = Key(aws_bucket, key_name)
        print "aws_key: ", aws_key
        aws_key.delete()
        print "after aws_key.delete()"
        return make_response(200)
    else:
        return make_response(500)

def make_response(status=200, content=None):
    """ Construct an HTTP response. Fine Uploader expects 'application/json'.
    """

    response = HttpResponse()
    response.status_code = status
    response['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    response.content = content
    return response

def is_valid_policy(policy_document):
    """ Verify the policy document has not been tampered with client-side
    before sending it off. 
    """
    bucket = development.AWS_EXPECTED_BUCKET
    parsed_max_size = development.AWS_MAX_SIZE
    print "check validity"

    # bucket = ''
    # parsed_max_size = 0


    for condition in policy_document['conditions']:
        if isinstance(condition, list) and condition[0] == 'content-length-range':
            parsed_max_size = condition[2]
        else:
            if condition.get('bucket', None):
                bucket = condition['bucket']

    return bucket == development.AWS_EXPECTED_BUCKET and parsed_max_size == development.AWS_MAX_SIZE

def sign_policy_document(policy_document):
    """ Sign and return the policy doucument for a simple upload.
    http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/#signyours3postform
    """
    policy = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(policy_document))
    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(development.AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())
    return {
        'policy': policy,
        'signature': signature
    }

def sign_headers(headers):
    """ Sign and return the headers for a chunked upload. """
    print "sign headers"
    return {
        'signature': base64.b64encode(hmac.new(development.AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY, headers, hashlib.sha1).digest())
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... I am not able to reproduce this. What is the output of `pip freeze`? And are there any stack traces or other useful log messages in the terminal?

Comment: The 500 error in the last line of your terminal log indicates something went wrong with the Django server. Is that your _entire_ `views.py`?

Comment: That is not the entire views.py, but it is the only part that involves fineuploader. After you mentioned that it's something on the Django server, I noticed on it reaches the `handle_delete` view, satisfies the `if boto` conditions, and should then call `make_response(200)`. Something seems to be going wrong on the `aws_key.delete()` call.

Comment: Are you able to confirm the file is not deleted in your S3 bucket or bucket logs?

Comment: It's definitely not deleting in the S3 bucket, but this is the log output:

`ab533fe4f29353147ee4d1dce424fd7f2ea937154f494030d5ee8e011bf1daef XXXXXX [17/Apr/2014:14:42:54 +0000] 10.194.64.24 ab533fe4f29353147ee4d1dce424fd7f2ea937154f494030d5ee8e011bf1daef 69A4741B5F003038 REST.DELETE.OBJECT b0245d00-e828-41cf-8aef-f874cf4a1fa3.jpg "DELETE /thisorthis/b0245d00-e828-41cf-8aef-f874cf4a1fa3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 204 - - 29221 26 - "-" "S3Console/0.4"`

Comment: After reading about [DELETE Bucket Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketDELETEpolicy.html), I don't think I have my bucket policy correctly configured...

Comment: Nice! You should set that as the answer if it is the case. Also, if this is true I can look into adding a try/catch to the delete method of the django server to clue in anyone who may encounter this in the future.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's my issue, I've had trouble finding good example bucket policies since the first three Google links for ["Amazon S3 Bucket Policy"](https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+bucket+policy&oq=amazon) on Amazon are deprecated.

Comment: Maybe our official blog post on setting up S3 would be of some use? http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I had not properly configured my S3 bucket policy to also allow DELETE requests from my server, hence the bucket logs were showing an error 204. I had allowed PUT and GET requests, hence uploading and retrieval worked, but not DELETE. I changed my bucket policy to be more like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx/*"
    }
  ]
}
```